# How to use inputs and post method

Tags: java, servlets, java-web-start

I'm starting to learn java web, and i need some insight on why my code isn't working
when i try to submit my code i notice that when i go to the pages where should be an alteration it doesn't show anything.

i'll show some code

> Post Method

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String titulo = request.getParameter("titulo");
        String imagem = request.getParameter("imagem");
        String descricao = request.getParameter("descricao");
        String categoria = request.getParameter("categoria");

        Noticias noticia = new Noticias();



         System.out.println(titulo);
        noticia.setTitulo(titulo);
        System.out.println(descricao);
        noticia.setDescricao(descricao);
        System.out.println(categoria);
        noticia.setCategoria(categoria);
        System.out.println(categoria);
        noticia.setImagem(imagem);

        Noticias.dados.add(noticia);

        response.sendRedirect(categoria);
    }
```

> Get Method

```
      @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }
```

> Inputs

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
    <input  class="form-control" id="titulo"  placeholder="Titulo">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imagem">Imagem</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="imagem"  placeholder="Imagem">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
    <input  class="form-control" id="descricao"  placeholder="Descrição">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
    <input  class="form-control" id="categoria"  placeholder="Categoria">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

my sysout's dont show any output.
and it doesn't show any alteration on the pages, i guess post isn't being initialized

Comment: You have not specify `action` and `method` attribute in your `<form>` tag .Also your `<input>` tags doesn’t have `name` attribute which will used by servlet to get requested values .

Comment: Thank you, i forgot about the name attribute <3

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting form you have to mention method and action attributes into form tag.

```
   <form action="servletname" method="post">
```

That servlet should be present into web.xml too.

You can follow this link https://www.journaldev.com/1877/servlet-tutorial-java